# Tuple vs Generic class Performance

Tags: c#

What's more performant a `Tuple<int, int>` or a `generic class` as follows:

```
   public class Interval<T>
    {
       public T From, To;

       public static Interval<T> Create(T from, T to)
       {
          Interval<T> range = new Interval<T>();

                range.From = from;
                range.To = to;

                return range;
            }
        }
   }
```

Usage scenario - large collections (100K++) of these objects get filtered using `LINQ`. I currently have generic classes, thinking of moving to something more fat-free and hopefully faster. Wonder if I I'll gain speed by switching to use `Tuple`'s?

Comment: Write some code to profile it

Comment: a `Tuple`, by the way, *is* a generic class.

Comment: I can't see any difference based on small tests I've conducted. I wanted to ask people if it's worth doing  that.

Comment: @Andrew Barber :) I know that.

Comment: @user1514042: You could consider using a generic *struct* instead of a class... perhaps. For `Interval` I'd expect some sort of comparison between values of `T`. But fundamentally, I very much doubt that you'll see any difference. If you have performance concerns, you should prove that they're actually a problem, and then test an alternative. Otherwise you'll almost certainly be optimizing the wrong bit of your code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Makes sense. Be honest a few months ago I re-wrote one of our modules to use struct's instead of classes, I spent couple days and got no performance improvement. Since then I never bother to use structures, was it just a bad use case, am I supposed to gain a lot just from using structs vs classes?

Comment: The difference between the two is not worth worrying about.  **IF** performance is a problem, you're not gonna find the solution here.  The ideal solution here is the one that makes more sense, not the "fastest" one.  Quit being a ricer and worrying about a nanosecond here or there, and fix the parts that *matter*.

Comment: Making `From` and `To` fields instead of properties (like in `Interval<T>`) will not make performance better in an optimised build (may be slightly faster in debug builds though).

Comment: @user1514042: That's the point - you've currently got them as public fields (urgh) and that's probably going to be the only real difference between what you've got and `Tuple<,>`. As for whether structures are faster than classes - it entirely depends on the use case. It's not a matter of one being universally "better" than the other.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Otherwise you'll almost certainly be optimizing the wrong bit of your code": Well said, I've never heard that expressed quite so concisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would look at the compiled code for a `Tuple<int, int>` and an `Interval<int>`, it would be hard to tell them apart.

The way that they are stored in memory will be identical.

---

You can also consider using a `struct` instead of a `class`:

```
public struct Interval<T> {

   public T From { get; private set; }
   public T To { get; private set; }

   public Interval(T from, T to) {
     From = from;
     To = to;
   }

}
```

Structs have a value semantics, so the usage would be different in some cases. It is not as simple to implement a well working struct (e.g. implementing relevant comparison and conversion), but it would save you a lot of memory. A class has an overhead of about 12 or 24 bytes (depending on the platform), which you don't get with a struct.

Comment: @Mudu value types are not necessarily stored on the stack.  See almost any article here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/Value+Types/, especially http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: @phoog Thank you for pointing this out. You're right of course.

Answer (score 1):

much more important is that you try to declare your object as a struct, if you are handling so large data collections. an array of structs is in the memory one piece, an array of class is one object for the array, and then for each member you have another object having the standard "class overhead"

Answer (score 1):

You have an answer by Jon Skeet so there's not much more to add. But you're apparently supposing that Tuple is implementing some kind of magic your generic class will not. I'm just looking at the source code of `Tuple<T1,T2>` now, and it's really the same thing than what you already have, except it encapsulates the fields in properties and implements ToString() and IStructuralComparable.

I'd look at the larger picture and start looking at other ways of optimizing, such as optimizing your LINQ queries, finding multiple enumerations of IEnumerable or using some kind of cache or lazy loading. You can't really optimize what seems to be just a structure containing two ints.